How Resolve The Multiline Log Issue Using Fluent-bit For Nextjs Logs
Iam running nextjs application in ecs with sidecar as fluent-bit. And My application logs look like this, No timestamp only this much like So what will i do for the creation of fluentbit config
`Received a request: {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/hello',
  headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    accept: '*/*',
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'x-middleware-invoke': '',
    'x-invoke-path': '/api/hello',
    'x-invoke-query': '%7B%7D',
    'x-invoke-output': '/api/hello',
    'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost:3000',
    'x-forwarded-port': '3000',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
    'x-forwarded-for': '::1'
  },
  body: {}
}`

Iam excpeting this logs come as one entry, Not splitted by multiline
